# Crash on IOS 6.0-6.1 Ipad only Admob and iAd

Tags: ipad, ios6, crash, admob, iad

I'm currently getting a crash thats holding my app out of the app store, it seems to occur when i create a google ad as a fall back for iAd. 
It only occurs on the I-pad running IOS 6.0 - 6.1 in compatibility mode (the app is not universal) and it appears to occur after the:
 [googleAdvertBanner loadRequest:releaseRequest];

Any help would be really appreciated, here's what i'm getting in the code view when i crash:

```
GADMAdNetworkConnectorImpl.m:95
0x49e008:  addl   $60, %esp  --- Thread 1:EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xf)
```

The log shows the following:

```
DBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0x13c9e380 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}
```

And my  app code for the ad handling:

```
#pragma mark Ad Banner Delegate
#pragma mark -

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    // remove the google advert banner

    [googleAdvertBanner removeFromSuperview];

    // dont use auto resizing mask for constraints

    advertBanner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // scroll the ad bar

    [self moveViews:adView down:YES];



    //NSLog(@"IAD advert has SUCCEEDED");

}


- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{

    // scroll the ad bar

    [self moveViews:adView down:NO];

    // create the google advert

    [self createGoogleAdvert];

    //NSLog(@"IAD advert has FAILED");

}




- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner{



}

#pragma mark GoogleAd Banner Delegate

#pragma mark -

- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)view{

    // dont use auto resizing mask for constraints

    googleAdvertBanner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // add the google advert banner

    [adView addSubview:googleAdvertBanner];

    // scroll the ad bar

    [self moveViews:adView down:YES];

    //NSLog(@"Google advert has SUCCEEDED");

}


- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error{

    // remove the google ad and instantiate the apple advert

    [googleAdvertBanner removeFromSuperview];

    // scroll the ad bar

    [self moveViews:adView down:NO];

    //NSLog(@"Google advert has FAILED");

}


- (void)adViewDidDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)adView{


}


#pragma mark Create GoogleAd Banner

#pragma mark -

- (void)createGoogleAdvert{

    // if the googleadvert banner has not been initiated

    if (!googleAdvertBanner) {

        // create google advert banner

        googleAdvertBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

    }

    // set the ads "unit identifier", delegate and root view controller

    googleAdvertBanner.adUnitID = @"myid which is correct";

    googleAdvertBanner.delegate = self;

    googleAdvertBanner.rootViewController = self;

    // test request

    //GADRequest *testRequest = [GADRequest request];

    //testRequest.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, @"0525457c40445ae54cac4f282ba0d409", nil];

    // release request

    GADRequest *releaseRequest = [GADRequest request];

    // load the request

    [googleAdvertBanner loadRequest:releaseRequest];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check internet reachability before performing GADRequest. I had experience with crashing on loading adMob banners offline.

```
if ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] isReachable]) {
  //... banner init etc

  // release request
  GADRequest *releaseRequest = [GADRequest request];
  // load the request
  [googleAdvertBanner loadRequest:releaseRequest];
 }
```

Comment: Thank for the info Yourik, i actaully do network checks before downloading Json, i'm not sure this is the issue though as the app works fine on iphone 4 and 5 on IOS 6 and upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Ok think i solved this issue:

I had my admob mediation also serving the iAd as well as having an adbannerview, and i believe that on the lower end IOS version 6.0-6.1 When the mediated iAd failed it was unable to call the failedToLoad as the adbannerview did not exist or it was simply couldnt run the method, removing the mediation from my admob setup solved the crash.